# Order details display ORDER BY date and name

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have applied query to show order details in a table according to names and dates. It shows data correct.Right now its displaying data like this:

[image]

But now i want my data to be shown in format where i can see all the orders from same client according to date something like this:

```
ABC ordered on Date:20/05/15

 ItemName | Size | Quantity | Color
 item1    |  XL  |     7    |  yellow
 item2    |  L   |     3    |  pink
 item3    |  S   |     1    |  green

XYZ ordered on Date:13/09/15

 ItemName | Size | Quantity | Color
 item1    |  L   |     8    |  brown
 item2    |  L   |     3    |  pink
 item3    |  S   |     4    |  green
```

Any suggestions or help will be appreciable

**Code**

```
 echo" <table border='3px' bordercolor='#333333' >";
 $query="select orders.date,order_detail.quantity,order_detail.price,order_detail.color,order_detail.size,customers.name,products.product_name,products.product_image from order_detail JOIN orders on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid Join customers on customers.serial=orders.customerid Join products on products.productid=order_detail.productid ";
 $sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
  ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
    </tr>
     <th>Product</th>
      <th>Name & quantity</th>
      <th>Color</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Size</th>
       <tr>
    <td><image width="80px" height="90px" src="\images<?php echo $row['product_image'] ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['product_name']. "*". $row['quantity']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['color'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      } }
    ?>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding order by this way

```
$query="select orders.date,order_detail.quantity,
  order_detail.price,order_detail.color,
  order_detail.size,customers.name,products.product_name,
  products.product_image from order_detail 
  JOIN orders on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid 
  Join customers on customers.serial=orders.customerid 
  Join products on products.productid=order_detail.productid 
  order by  orders.date ASC, product.name ASC";
```

Comment: It will still show the date and name with each row.

Comment: What do you mean... the result of the query is only ordered in the way defined with the order by.. the fact you show the date and the name in a row or in two is related to your html

Comment: Otherwise if you want a master detail structure of the document you should do a master query for the order and foreach a detil query for the item ..

Comment: I hope this is useful

Comment: I'll try this for sure

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group BY Order_date`. If there are multiple orders from same customer Use `SUM(quantity)` and `distinct(Itemname)`.

Comment: if you can provide a proper query it will help me understand more